# Indexed object type where the value is a function of the key?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
type ShapeParams = {
    rectangle: { x:number, y:number, width:number, height:number},
    circle: { x:number, y:number, radius:number }
};

type ActualShapes = {
    [shapeName in keyof ShapeParams]:{
        [paramName in keyof ShapeParams[shapeName]]: number
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

But is it what you want?

Check https://repl.it/repls/ParchedComfortableGnudebugger and hover your mouse over `ActualShapes` to see if this is the desired type.